# Jade and whitespaces

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I'm starting to play with jade and got stuck with this:

I want to output something like:

```
  hey! this
is pre
     text!!!
```

I use tabs for indentation in templates and if I write spaces at the beginning of lines I get not both tabs & spaces indentation error.

My jade template:

```
div
    pre.  hey! this
        is pre
             text!!!
```

Have also tried with "|" syntax.

So, how can I output this?  Thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, was simple or just mistyped something:

```
pre
  |  hey! this
  |      is pre
  |           text!!!
```

Also got it to work using &nbsp; as the first "space" character and "." syntax

```
pre.
  &nbsp; hey! this
  &nbsp;      is pre
  &nbsp;          text!
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

## view.jade

```
a.nav
  i.user
  nbsp
  | Me
```

## style.css

```
nbsp {
  width: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```